# $x^2+ax+b=0 \overset ? \impliedby (A,+,\cdot)$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $(A,+,\cdot)$ be a ring with $|A|=9$. Prove that the next statements are equivalent:

a) For all $x\in A-\{0\}$ there exist $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$ and $b \in \{-1,1\}$ s.t.   $x^2+ax+b=0$.

b) $(A,+,\cdot)$ is a field

1. a) $\implies$ b)

   If  $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$ then

\begin{aligned}
ax&=xa \\
x(x+a)&=(x+a)x=b \in\{-1,1\}.
\end{aligned}
So $x$ is invertible and $(A,+, \cdot)$ is a field.

I don't know how to show that b) $\implies$ a). Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: If $A$ is a field then $A\cong\Bbb{F}_9$,  for which it is quickly verified that such $a$ and $b$ exist for all $x\neq0$.

Comment: Also, it seems that you proved that if $a)$ holds, then $A$ is a *skew-field* a.k.a. a *division ring*. It remains to prove that $A$ is commutative.

Answer (score 3):

The proof of (a)$\implies$(b) is not complete as you have not shown that multiplication is commutative. This follows from Wedderburn's theorem that every finite division ring is commutative, but we can avoid using the sledgehammer.

You know that $F=\{0,1,-1\}$ is a subfield of $A$ and is certainly contained in the center. Hence $A$ is a two-dimensional vector space over $F$, so it has a basis $\{1,x\}$ and every element is of the form $a+bx$, for $a,b\in F$. Hence any two elements commute. (Note that for this you don't even need that $A$ is a division ring, so this might go before the proof that every element of $A\setminus\{0\}$ is invertible.)

More generally, if $A$ is a ring of cardinality $p^2$, with $p$ a prime, then $A$ is commutative.

For the converse, you know that $A$ has characteristic $3$, so it is a two-dimensional field extension of $F=\{0,1,-1\}$. For the nonzero elements of $F$ there is no problem in finding the suitable $a$ and $b$. If $x\in A\setminus F$, it has a degree $2$ minimal polynomial over $F$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And I edited my answer accordingly.